# Use the limit definition to find the slope of the tangent line at a point

Tags: calculus

Use the limit definition to find the slope of the tangent line to the graph of $f(x)=\sqrt{8x+1}$ at the point $(6,7)$.

I sort of get how to do this but the square root is making it difficult. I know there is way but I don't remember. Can someone show how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you show us what you have tried so far? This will make it easyer for people to see where you get stuck. Also, as a new user you might want to read the [tutorial](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** After you set it up, make use of this algebraic manipulation:

$$\sqrt {u} - \sqrt {v} \;\; = \;\; \frac{\sqrt {u} - \sqrt {v}}{1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt {u} + \sqrt {v}}{\sqrt {u} + \sqrt {v}} \;\; = \;\; \frac{u-v}{\sqrt {u} + \sqrt {v}} $$

In your case, $u$ will be $8(6+h) + 1$ and $v$ will be $8\cdot6 + 1.$

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
f'(6)&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(6+h)-f(6)}{h}
\\&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\sqrt{8(6+h)+1}-7}{h}
\\&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\sqrt{8(6+h)+1}-7}{h}\times\frac{\sqrt{8(6+h)+1}+7}{\sqrt{8(6+h)+1}+7}
\\&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{8(6+h)+1-49}{h(\sqrt{8(6+h)+1}+7)}
\\&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{8h}{h(\sqrt{8(6+h)+1}+7)}
\\&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{8}{\sqrt{8(6+h)+1}+7}
\\&=\frac{8}{14}\\&=\frac{4}{7}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @CSES Glad to help!